# Print/save immediate window results - log to a file

Tags: logging, printing, immediate-window

I'm wondering if there is a way to print all info from, the Immediate window into a file or direct back to a specific cell?

When the code runs, it shows results in the Immediate window, but in the moment I need to copy/paste them to a cell or to another .txt file.
So it would be great if I can log or print all the results after the analysis into a file (on my desktop) or just back into cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it myself, so the problem is solved

```
    If UBound(XX) > 0 Then Print #n, Join(XX, ",")
```

Where Debug.Print was changed with Print #n

```
    n = FreeFile()
    Open "C:\Users\" & Environ$("username") & "\Desktop\Results.txt" For Output As #n
```